# Daisy chain of two monitors through DisplayPort does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04, but I can't get it to handle two monitor setup(both Dell U2518D with MST support).

One monitor connected to DP works alright.
When I connect the second monitor (Dell U2414H) to the first one through DisplayPort (daisy chain), the second monitor just mirrors the content of the first one.
The second monitor not shown in Settings->Displays, only the first one.

When I go into the setting on the first monitor using it's OSD and enable MST both screens go black and previously seen one display dissapear from ubuntu display settings).

Side note:
Worth mentioning that the entire setup works fine on Windows 10 and both screens are treated as separate screens. I have also tried Fedora 32 and Ubuntu 18.04 but same poop with all Linux distributions. For both Ubuntu 20.04 and Fedora 32 I have installed latest nvidia drivers, but that didn't help.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I am in the same boat, have you resolved this?

Comment: Generally, MST requires DP1.2+. If you have two graphics cards, could it be that one of them does not support DP1.2 and is being used?

Comment: @sup, you are not going to like it... i switched to MacBook :/ :D I was not able to find the solution for Ubuntu, so I have given up

Comment: @IljaLeiko as a counterpoint, I have been running two 1440p monitors through DP MST on Ubuntu 18 and 20, and on both a desktop and a laptop. It does work

Comment: @IljaLeiko what is your integrated graphics, and can you check if it is being used by Ubuntu?

Comment: @lija Leiko: actually, for me, I had to enable MST in the monitor settings (in hardware, using the buttons directly on the monitor) and then it just worked.